# Unbiased Estimator of $\sigma^{2}$ from Error (disturbance) term

Tags: regression, parameter-estimation, linear-regression, regression-analysis

How can I show that

$E[\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}^{2}] =  n\sigma^2$

to prove that

$ \sum u_{i}^{2} $ is an unbiased estimator of $n\sigma^{2}$?

Let $u$ denote the error (disturbance) term from the simple linear regression model $y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{i} + u_{i} $

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Comment: I got to the relation where $\hat{u}_{i} = u_{i} - (\hat{\beta}_{0} - \beta_{0}) - (\hat{\beta}_{1} - \beta_{1})x_{i}$ but then I'm stuck and confused when it comes to squaring and summations.